# How to get openweathermap.org info by zip?

Tags: api, weather-api

I'm trying to retrieve weather info through openweathermap.org. No matter which zipcode I put in, it always return Not found city.

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=98104,us&APPID=xxx
```

> {"cod":"404","message":"Error: Not found city"}

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried with my id and it didn't work either. It might be a server overload.
You may want to fill a support request with openWeatherMap themselves, this is what I found from a while back:

from https://openweathermap.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/13084185-error-not-found-city: 
Ivan - Sep 15, 2015 03:51PM UTC - OpenWeatherMap Agent

> To make it clear: a problem of our API is that errors like this don’t
>   necessarily mean what they say. A 404 or, say, 503 error can happen
>   even when your request is perfectly valid and when the place actually
>   is in the database, the reason behind is the free servers overload. We
>   do our best to extend the capacity continuously but don’t always
>   manage fitting in the resources we have